# Quantization through the logarithm function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I've been trying to figure out why my quantization method through the logarithm doesn't seem to work. C1 is the original image, I just split them into the three bands and then attempted to quantize:

```
OredChannel  = uint8(double(C1(:,:,1)));
OgreenChannel = uint8(double(C1(:,:,2)));
OblueChannel = uint8(double(C1(:,:,3)));

MaxR = 1/max(double(OredChannel(:)));
NatImgR = uint8(MaxR * log(double(OredChannel)));
MaxG = 1/max(double(OgreenChannel(:)));
NatImgG = uint8(MaxG *log(double(OgreenChannel)));
MaxB = 1/max(double(OblueChannel(:)));
NatImgB = uint8(MaxB * log(double(OblueChannel)));
CLog = cat(3,NatImgR,NatImgG,NatImgB);
imshow(CLog);
title('Part F: Natural Logarithm');
```

I only seem to get a black screen though. I've tried adding 1 and 1/3 on all the bands but doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Think about what you are doing: you start with a number in the range 0-255, take the logarithm, which makes it smaller, then multiply by a small value that is guaranteed to make the result less than 1. Then you convert to an integer. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Ahhh. That explains that. Trying to figure out the right constant that would make the logarithm go to the proper range. I had thought that that constant would've been the right one.

Comment: Tried 255/Max, I don't believe that's the right constant is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on your code for just one channel:

```
MaxR = 1/max(double(OredChannel(:)));
NatImgR = uint8(MaxR * log(double(OredChannel)));
```

`MaxR` is defined such that `MaxR*double(OredChannel)` is at most 1. Casting this to `uint8` will give you an image with mostly 0s, and 1 where the input was maximal. Adding the `log` in the mix makes it so that the result is a much smaller value, which cast to `uint8` is guaranteed to give 0.

For quantizing logarithmically (using natural logarithm as you seem intent on doing), you can do as follows:

```
NatImgR = exp(floor(log(double(OredChannel))));
```

`floor` returns an integer value between 0 and 5 (assuming input values in the range [0,255]), and `-Inf` where the input was 0. To bring that back to the original input range, I apply `exp`, which is of course the inverse of `log`. This leads to the following 7 possible output values (assuming input values are integers):

```
>> unique(NatImgR(:))
ans =
         0
    1.0000
    2.7183
    7.3891
   20.0855
   54.5982
  148.4132
```

You can cast that to `uint8` if you wish; that will round the values, leading to the possible values `[0,1,3,7,20,55,148]`.

To change the number of quantization levels, scale the input. If the max is below `exp(n-1)`, you'll have `n` quantization levels:

```
n = 5;
scale = exp(n-1) / (max(double(OredChannel(:)))+1);
NatImgR = exp(floor(log(round(scale*double(OredChannel)))));
```

A few things to note:

- `scale` is computed using `max()+1`. The +1 is to ensure that the input values are *below* `exp(n-1)`, never equal (as that would introduce one more quantization level).
- I use `round` after scaling and before taking the logarithm. This is to avoid quantization levels in between 0 and 1: the scaling can introduce non-integer values in between 0 and 1, leading to potentially many quantization levels in that range.

Comment: Hmm I tried doing the quantization here: NatImgR = exp(floor(log(double(OredChannel))));
 and then when I put the three bands together I don't seem to get anything but a blank graph and not a picture.

Comment: The result of that operation is a double array. `imshow` assumes those are in the range [0,1], and will clip higher values. You need to scale the output or convert to `uint8` before displaying.

Comment: I did this and it still happens:NatImgR = uint8(exp(floor(log(double(OredChannel)))));
NatImgG = uint8(exp(floor(log(double(OgreenChannel)))));
NatImgB = uint8(exp(floor(log(double(OblueChannel)))));
Clog1 = cat(3,NatImgR,NatImgG,NatImgB);
imshow(Clog1);
No11 = figure;
title('Part F: Natural Logarithm');

Comment: Then there is an issue with the input values. For `OredChannel=0:255` this yields the expected output. If your input is in the range [0,1] it's not going to work.

Comment: Hmmm I'm just trying to figure out the proper ratio to do so. since you said casting the NatImgRs would get the proper values.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the values, it changes the representation. (Well, it changes the values if they cannot be represented in the new type.) if your input is in the range [0,1], simply multiply by 255 first.

Comment: Well looking at the NatImgR, G and B seem to give numbers like 55 and 148, and 7, 3 and 1, following your answer. Even if I did multiply with 255 as you've stated.

Comment: To display an image with values in the range [0,255] you should either cast it to `uint8` or divide by 255 to bring it in the [0,1] range. `imshow` wants its input in that format. Alternatively, do `imshow(img,[0,255])`. Please read the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html